# Unwanted Inner box-shadow on input field

Tags: css

I want to apply two box-shadows with a 90 degree angle to my `input` field, so I expect the shadows to be only at the top and bottom borders, but not at the left and right borders. Instead, there is a dark inset shadow on the left that I can't get rid of (see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9jma/)). Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean by unwanted? you are using `inset`,so if you want top and left shadow outside of your input field do it like this instead

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/T9jma/2/)

CSS

```
input{
    margin: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px #888;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

And if you want to give `inset` to just top and bottom do it like this

[**Inset Top Bottom Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/T9jma/4/)

CSS

```
input{
    margin: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 11px 8px -10px #888, inset 0px -11px 8px -10px #888;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

Note: I've added borders, you can remove though

Comment: Sorry that my question wasn't clearer. One of the two shadows should be inset (dark, only top border), the other not inset (light, only bottom). The problem was a dark inset border on the LEFT that I don't want there. But you solved my problem anyway: the `border` did the trick ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9jma/5/)). So thanks a lot for the quick answer!

Comment: @Jo. no problem, actually I got confused so ;) and you welcome